# How to unit test a class when internal details matter a lot?

Tags: c#

I am not sure about how such a pattern named or even if it exists, but I named it 'container pattern'.

What I am trying to accomplish: to have an abstraction to hold a list of entities, being able only to add entities, and remove them only when entities saved to the database. I must say it works quite well and I like it much more than passing around List<> like I did earlier.
I just learned that testing private fields is big no-no, but I don't know how I can test Add method alone. Or how to test SaveAndClean without invoking Add. So far testing private field using additional constructor seem clean, but probably there are better solutions.

```
namespace test
{
    class Container
    {
        private readonly List<Entity> _results;
        private readonly IRepostory _repo;

        // used for prod
        public Container(IRepostory repo)
        : this(new List<Entity>(500000), repo)
        {
        }
        
        // used for tests
        internal Container(List<Entity> results, IRepostory repo)
        {
            _results = results;
            _repo = repo;
        }

        public void Add(Entity entity)
        {
            _results.Add(entity);
        }

        public async Task<bool> SaveAndClearAsync()
        {
            if (!_results.Any())
            {
                return true;
            }
            
            try
            {
                await _repo.SaveAsync(_results);
                _results.Clear();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // logging
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

```
[Fact]
public void Add_AddToExisting_EntityAdded()
{
    // Arrange
    var results = new List<Entity>();
    results.Add(new Entity { Name = "md51" });
    var repo = new Mock<IRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var service = new Container(results, repo.Object);
    var newEntity = new Entity { Name "md52" };

    // Act
    service.Add(newEntity);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal("md51", results[0].Name);
    Assert.Equal("md52", results[1].Name);
    Assert.Equal(2, results.Count);
}
```

Comment: Well, on second glance, this doesn't look too bad. Your methods have sideeffects on the injected datastructures, so that's the only way you can confirm that the expected sideeffects have actually happened.

Comment: You _could_ avoid injecting the list, if you added a "Length" or "Count" property. I mean: the actual order doesn't really matter, does it? If you add an item, you expect the count to rise by 1. Just as an idea.

Comment: Indeed, maybe it's a complication because of side effects. I chose it deliberately to avoid costly often memory allocations leading to memory fragmentation and OOM.

Comment: You could add a public property to acces the list values. `public List<Entity> Results => _results;`

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would test the behavior as a black box. And from a black box perspective only calling Add doesn't produce any behavior so I'd leave it at that. But calling `Add()` 2 times and `SaveAndClearAsync` does, so just test that.

You shouldn't change your code interface for the sole purpose of testing. That's an anti-pattern as well.

I recommend [this](https://youtu.be/SQUI9Ixb790) Dave Farley video on test mistakes.

Comment: AFAIR unit tests should also have only one reason to fail. Calling `Add` when testing `SaveAndClearAsync ` also violates that principle.

Comment: I know this is old, but take a look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W40mpZP9xQQ State change test is one of the 3 and you would assert it by calling other public methods of the class